# Getting an error in a SOQL

Tags: soql

I am using below query in a batch class

```
Query='Select Id FROM Contact WHERE SyncToMarketo__c  = true ' 
            + ' AND LastModifiedDate >= :date.today().addDays(-1) ';
```

and get an error in logs **unexpected token: (**
but the same works good in the anonymous window.
Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dynamic SOQL (where the SOQL is a string) dotted expressions are not supported for bind variables (that follow the `:`).

Best approach is to use static SOQL instead and that way you also get more syntax checking done for you. So:

```
Contact[] contacts = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM Contact
        WHERE SyncToMarketo__c = true
        AND LastModifiedDate >= :Date.today().addDays(-1)
        ];
```

If you have a reason to use dynamic SOQL, then this should work providing the query is executed where `d` is *still in scope*:

```
Date d = Date.today().addDays(-1)
String q = ''
        + ' SELECT Id'
        + ' FROM Contact'
        + ' WHERE SyncToMarketo__c = true' 
        + ' AND LastModifiedDate >= :d';
...
Contact[] contacts = (Contact[]) Database.query(q);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding but is there any other way to write the same in a dynamic query?

Comment: @gs650x See last bit of code I just added.

Answer (score 2):

Posted query will not work in anonymous block as well. You could try something like

```
Date dt = date.today().addDays(-1);
string Query='Select Id FROM Contact WHERE SyncToMarketo__c = true ' 
            + ' AND LastModifiedDate >= :dt';
Database.query(Query);
```

For efficiency you can try with `YESTERDAY`

```
string Query = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SyncToMarketo__c = true AND LastModifiedDate >= YESTERDAY';
```

More on [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) here.

Comment: Yeah Date Literal makes *way* more sense for this use case.